# free() : invalid pointer and how to reuse a currently freed pointer

Tags: c, free

I want to address my pointer to another object and free the memory of previous object. This is what I did but I had a invalid pointer error. What is the right way to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int number = 5;
    int number2 = 10;

    // Give memory manually 
    int *pointer2number = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    pointer2number = &number;

    printf("Number is %i\n", number);       
    printf("Address of number is %p\n", pointer2number);

    // Free memory 
    free(pointer2number);
    pointer2number = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    pointer2number = &number2;
    printf("New number is %i\n", *pointer2number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your assignment on the line after the `malloc` line, you overwrite the pointer that `malloc` gave you.

Comment: I'm not really "c-guy" but I'd say you are not using your mallocs but address of number and number2

Comment: Oh right now i understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int *pointer2number = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
pointer2number = &number;
```

You assign the address of `number` to the pointer `pointer2number` and with that replace the address of the allocated dynamic memory stored in `pointer2number` before.

The same goes for the second attempt with `number2`.

Any attempt to `free()` a memory not previously allocated by a memory-management function, invokes undefined behavior:

> "*The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined**.*"
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), Section 7.22.3.3/2

And as side-effect, the previously allocated dynamic memory isn´t `free()`d with that too.

Overthink the logic of your program!

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much